# Определение щелчка по строке SVG на расстоянии <= 3 пикселей

Tags: javascript, css, svg, hover

Вот как я определяю клики по строкам SVG:

```js
window.onmousedown = (e) => {
    if (e.target.tagName == 'line') {
        alert();  // do something with e.target
    }
}
```

```css
svg line:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg">
<line x1="320" y1="160" x2="140" y2="00" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"></line>
<line x1="140" y1="00" x2="180" y2="360" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"></line>
<line x1="180" y1="360" x2="400" y2="260" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"></line>
<line x1="00" y1="140" x2="280" y2="60" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"></line>
</svg>
```

Это работает только в том случае, если курсор мыши находится точно на линии, что непросто, так что это плохой UX.

**Как определить клик по строке SVG из Javascript, пусть даже не идеально по линии, а на расстоянии <= 3 пикселя?**

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Detect a click on a SVG line even at a distance of 3 pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71699394/7394871) от участника  [@Basj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1422096/basj).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/71699394/7394871

Comment: Тема актуальна, поднималась много раз в разных вариациях, поэтому всячески приветствуются новые, самостоятельные ответы. Плюсы и галочка гарантированы для хороших ответов!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Решение с одним `<line>` и небольшим количеством JavaScript было бы
> интересным.

Мы можем использовать существующий веб-API `document.elementFromPoint(x, y)`. Он возвращает самый верхний элемент в данной точке.
Сформировав точку клика пользователя, мы можем перемещаться по каждой оси и находить первый элемент `<line>` с помощью метода. Мы останавливаем поиск, когда получаем строку или достигаем максимального расстояния поиска.

В следующей демонстрации не было создано никаких дополнительных элементов. Переменная близость управляет максимальным расстоянием от линии, чтобы учитывать ее для выбора.
Бонусная функция: подсвечивается ближайшая к указателю мыши линия. Таким образом, пользователь может легко щелкнуть нужную строку без каких-либо хлопот.

```js
const proximity = 8;

const directions = [
  [0, 0],
  [0, 1], [0, -1],
  [1, 1], [-1, -1],
  [1, 0], [-1, 0],
  [-1, 1], [1, -1]
];

// tracks nearest line
let currentLine = null;

// highlight nearest line to mouse pointer
container.onmousemove = (e) => {
  let line = getNearestLine(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  if (line) {
    if (currentLine !== line)
      currentLine?.classList.remove('highlight');

    currentLine = line;
    currentLine.classList.add('highlight');
    container.classList.add('pointer');
  } else {
    currentLine?.classList.remove('highlight');
    currentLine = null;
    container.classList.remove('pointer')
  }
}

container.onclick = (e) => {
  // we already know in 'onmousemove' which line is the nearest
  // so no need to figure it out again.
  log.textContent = currentLine ? currentLine.textContent : '';
}

// find a nearest line within 'proximity'
function getNearestLine(x, y) {
  // move along each axis and see if we land on a line
  for (let i = 1; i <= proximity; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < directions.length; j++) {
      const xx = x + directions[j][0] * i;
      const yy = y + directions[j][1] * i;
      const element = document.elementFromPoint(xx, yy);
      if (element?.tagName == 'line')
        return element;
    };
  }
  return null;
}
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: wheat;
}

.pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.highlight {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 4px black);
}

#log {
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Clicked on: <span id="log"></span></p>
<svg id='container' width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg">
    <line x1="320" y1="160" x2="140" y2="00" stroke="red" stroke-width="2">1</line>
    <line x1="140" y1="00" x2="180" y2="360" stroke="green" stroke-width="2">2</line>
    <line x1="18" y1="60" x2="400" y2="60" stroke="orange" stroke-width="2">3</line>
    <line x1="00" y1="140" x2="280" y2="60" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2">4</line>
  </svg>
```

Это просто демонстрационный код, от которого можно избавиться. Если вы не хотите, чтобы курсор - рука показывалась в непосредственной близости, удалите `onmousemove` и переместите логику в метод `onclick`.
Только `filter: drop-shadow(...)` может выделять неквадратные формы. В противном случае вы можете изменить ширину или цвет линии и т. д.

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71733126/7394871) от участника  [@the Hutt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15273968/the-hutt).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Немного сложное решение, но работает:

```js
window.onmousedown = (e) => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('line')) {
        console.log(e.target.href);
    }
}
```

```css
svg .line:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.line {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
.line.stroke {
  stroke: transparent;
  stroke-width: 6px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg">
    <defs>
      <line id="line1" x1="320" y1="160" x2="140" y2="00"></line>
      <line id="line2" x1="140" y1="00" x2="180" y2="360"></line>
      <line id="line3" x1="180" y1="360" x2="400" y2="260"></line>
      <line id="line4" x1="00" y1="140" x2="280" y2="60"></line>
    </defs>
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#line1" class="line stroke"></use>
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#line1" class="line"></use>
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#line2" class="line stroke"></use>
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#line2" class="line"></use>
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#line3" class="line stroke"></use>
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#line3" class="line"></use>
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#line4" class="line stroke"></use>
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#line4" class="line"></use>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71699768/7394871) от участника  [@syduki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13993967/syduki).</sub>